# unicode error in .prettify() python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape websites using requests and BeautifulSoup4 packages.

```
>>>import requests
>>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>>r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms = coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA')

>>>r.content #shows source code (mess) bytes type

>>>soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
```

When I try to prettify and display the html code of the page with

`print(soup.prettify())`

I get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode the character '\u2013'
in position 44379: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried

```
>>>soupbytes = soup.prettify(encoding = 'utf-8') #this is bytes format
>>>soupstr = soupbytes.decode('utf-8') #this is str format
```

With the first one I don't get any problem to print (`print(soupbytes)`), but it doesn't print the text 'pretty', and it is bytes format. If I try to print the second one (`print(soupstr)`) I get the error again but I get the object in str type.

I have to say also that I don't get any error in the IDE (spyder). It's to say, if I run the next code in spyder:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?
search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA')

r.content #muestra html de la pagina
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I don't have any error and it is printed nicely.
Why is that difference? And how could I avoid the error in the terminal???

Comment: This may sound strange, but could you please do python --version  in terminal, to see if your running the script with the python version you think you are, its common to have unicode issues on python 2, and you might be calling the python3 interpreter through the IDE but not from the command line

Comment: Your terminal might not support UTF8

Comment: Can't reproduce this, you should make sure you're running python3 as suggested and also give us some details about your OS/environment.

Comment: I get version 3.5.2. I'm running python 3! 
I'd say that maybe you aren't coping it right because of the estructure of `r` in my post (it is in written in two lines when actually it should be just one). 
Sorry! I don't know what you want to say with OS/environment (windows???).


The answer about my terminar not supporting 'utf-8' makes sense, I didn't know that it could be possible, is it??
Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that the output of prettify just doesn't have Windows line endings? You can test that that writing the output of prettify to a file and then opening it with a text editor.

Comment: the line ending of prettify is `\n` . I achieve to print something with the order `print(soup.prettify(encoding = 'utf-8'))`, but this is printing an object of bytes type, so the line ending (`\n`) aren't interpreted. And I have checked that a str object is well printed ( i.e. the line endings are interpreted right). I hope you where asking about this fact!

Comment: The windows line ending is not `\n` though. Can you just write the output to a file and then examine it with a decent text editor? This all seems to be mostly related to your terminal.

Comment: That works in a text editor! Could I do something to see it well in the terminal and not getting an error?